# Frequent Communication between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities Activity A and Activity B that needs to communicate very frequently, if i will use startActivity on both activities then every times it will create new instances of them.
If i will use launchMode as singleTask then suppose from Activity A i call Activity B then if Activity B doesn't exist in the Task, new Instance of Activity B will be created in the Task and that will be on top of the Task, Now if i will call Activity A from B then Activity B will gets cleared from Task(singleTask makes A as the root Activity).Again calling B from A will create new Instance of B but i want if the the Activities exist in Task then it should not create new Instances.

How do i achieve this ?, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case why are you trying to have two activity instances at the same time which is against the design of android. You can also use Fragments within your activity to fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think better option is to use observer pattern. Use broadcast receiver to send the message between activities.